# How to animate the triangles within a hexagon in 3d Max?

Tags: animation, 3ds-max

Basically I have created this structure 
[image]

and what I would like to do now is to animate the triangles within each hexagon so that they will open up like this.[image]

If anyone has any idea on how I could do this, please let me know.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Bun venit pe GraphicDesign!

Comment: Multumesc mult!

Comment: You should probably add some details as to how you created the structure, if you have access to each hexagon individually, if it's converted to editable poly and so on. Maybe encourage people to help by adding more information.

Comment: You can use morph function